# Undo a Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I'm trying to change something from a data frame into a string.
peak1 is my data frame that is 1 row and 5 columns. I just want one part of it under the column 'url' and make it into a string.

```
buzz1 = peak1[['url']]
```

However, buzz1 returns:

```
                                                     buzz
379635  http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/01/02/karda...
```

379635 is the userid associated with this.

Comment: What is the output you're trying to get?  Do you want to modify the url, or change the userid to a string instead of an integer?

Comment: That returns a dataframe consisting of a single column, if you want just the value then you could do `peak1['url'][0]`

Comment: Please see my answer and ignore my previous comment, that would only work if your first value had index `0` as @DSM pointed out, using `iloc` (see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) will return you the value at that index position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command returns a dataframe consisting of a single column, this is why you see the index column.

So what you want to do is to return just the first value from the series:

```
peak1['url'].iloc[0]
```

Will give you what you want.

Comment: That won't return the first value from the series; it'll return the value associated with the index 0.  The first value would be something like `peak1['url'].iloc[0]`.

Comment: @DSM yes that is true, I will update my answer, I had tested on my own toy example without considering the OP's data, thanks